# Obtain lockstate from Apache DavLockDB / WebDAV

Tags: php, apache, locking, webdav

I run an Apache webserver with mod_dav/mod_dav_fs on a windows server.
Users can edit certain files via WebDAV.

WebDAV is set up and running correctly so far...
The question is, how can I find out if and which files are currently opened via WebDAV?

Apache writes this info into its "DavLockDB".
Is there a way to read that file or to find out which files are currently locked?

I already tried it with via php:

```
$fp = fopen($file, 'c');
if (!flock($fp, LOCK_EX|LOCK_NB, $wouldblock)) {
    // lock  not obtained
    echo 'file maybe open';
}
else {
    // lock obtained
    echo 'file is free';    
}
```

This gives me a correct result if the file is opened locally on the server, but not if the file is opened via WebDAV.

Has anyone ever had a similar problem?

Kind regards
Thomas

Comment: I helped myself by reading the apache CustomLog backwards for "LOCK" and "UNLOCK" entries for the desired ressource

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been tied to and frustrated by WebDAV for some years, and I often had a need to be able to identify locked files and occasionally unlock them. I recently wrote a small tool in PHP to achieve this that you can see on [Github](https://github.com/webfoolery/webdav-browser).

Most of my answers were found in the [RFC document](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918#section-9.1) & on the [webdav.org](http://www.webdav.org/specs/rfc2518.html#METHOD_LOCK) site.I didn't encounter a solution using the DavLockDB and went the official route sending cURL requests to the DAV server as a real application would with HTTP verbs to get the info that I needed about files or directories.

In short you choose a file or directory as an endpoint and send PROPFIND request. If the endpoint is a directory you'll get a list of resources (files/directories) & their properties that are in that directory (and possibly under it depending on your DEPTH setting). If the endpoint is a file you'll get the file properties. In both cases the information is returned as XML and if any resource is locked the properties will include a LockToken.

Here's a PHP function that you could use based on a method in the repository noted above:

```
function propfind() {
    $location = 'https://example.com:8000' // ROUTE TO SERVER
    $endpoint = '/webdav/'; // FINAL DESTINATION
    $auth = 'user:pass'; // BASE64 ENCODED USERNAME:PASSWORD
    $url = $location.$endpoint;
    $host = parse_url($location, PHP_URL_HOST);
    $ch = curl_init();
    // FIX LOCALHOST SSL CERTIFICATE ISSUES
    if ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == 'localhost') curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
    $verbose = fopen('php://temp', 'w+'); // CREATE A STREAM TO SAVE THE VERBOSE CONNECTION DATA
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $verbose);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PROPFIND');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: text/xml; charset="utf-8"',
        'Host: '.$host, 
        'Authorization: Basic '.$auth, 
        'Depth: 1', 
    ));
    /*
    // OPTIONALLY LIMIT THE RESPONSE TO SPECIFIC PROPERTIES
    $xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?><D:propfind xmlns:D="DAV:"><D:prop><D:creationdate/><D:getlastmodified/><D:getcontentlength/></D:prop></D:propfind>';
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
    */
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    $curlInfo = curl_getinfo($ch);
    rewind($verbose);
    $verboseLog = stream_get_contents($verbose);
    if(curl_error($ch)) {
        return array('error'=>curl_errno($ch).': '.curl_error($ch), 'response'=>print_r($curlInfo,1), 'verbose'=>$verboseLog);
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    return array($response, $verboseLog);
}
```

A sample response might be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<D:multistatus xmlns:D="DAV:">
    <D:response xmlns:lp1="DAV:" xmlns:lp2="http://apache.org/dav/props/">
        <D:href>/webdav/test.xlsx</D:href>
        <D:propstat>
            <D:prop>
                <lp1:resourcetype/>
                <lp1:creationdate>2020-04-11T20:30:58Z</lp1:creationdate>
                <lp1:getcontentlength>9853</lp1:getcontentlength>
                <lp1:getlastmodified>Thu, 06 Aug 2020 16:17:05 GMT</lp1:getlastmodified>
                <lp1:getetag>"123456-789b-ab12345cd67e89"</lp1:getetag>
                <lp2:executable>T</lp2:executable>
                <D:supportedlock>
                    <D:lockentry>
                        <D:lockscope><D:exclusive/></D:lockscope>
                        <D:locktype><D:write/></D:locktype>
                    </D:lockentry>
                    <D:lockentry>
                        <D:lockscope><D:shared/></D:lockscope>
                        <D:locktype><D:write/></D:locktype>
                    </D:lockentry>
                </D:supportedlock>
                <D:lockdiscovery>
                    <D:activelock>
                        <D:locktype><D:write/></D:locktype>
                        <D:lockscope><D:exclusive/></D:lockscope>
                        <D:depth>infinity</D:depth>
                        <ns0:owner xmlns:ns0="DAV:"><ns0:href>Username</ns0:href></ns0:owner>
                        <D:timeout>Second-896</D:timeout>
                        <D:locktoken>
                            <D:href>opaquelocktoken:a12bc34d-567e-8901-23d4-5ab6cd7e8f90</D:href>
                        </D:locktoken>
                    </D:activelock>
                </D:lockdiscovery>
                <D:getcontenttype>application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet</D:getcontenttype>
            </D:prop>
            <D:status>HTTP/1.1 200 OK</D:status>
        </D:propstat>
    </D:response>
</D:multistatus>
```

Note the <D:locktoken> entry which indicates that the file is locked. In theory you could use the function recursively to map out the whole resource and highlight any locked files.

To unlock a file you need the credentials of the user that created the lock. Then send the request using UNLOCK as the HTTP verb:

```
function unlock () {
    $lockToken = 'opaquelocktoken:a12bc34d-567e-8901-23d4-5ab6cd7e8f90';
    $location = 'https://example.com:8000' // ROUTE TO SERVER
    $endpoint = '/webdav/'; // FINAL DESTINATION
    $auth = 'user:pass'; // BASE64 ENCODED USERNAME:PASSWORD
    $url = $location.$endpoint;
    $host = parse_url($location, PHP_URL_HOST);
    $ch = curl_init();
    // FIX LOCALHOST SSL CERTIFICATE ISSUES
    if ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == 'localhost') curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'UNLOCK');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Host: '.$host, 
        'Authorization: Basic '.$auth, 
        'Lock-Token: <'.$lockToken.'>', 
    ));
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    $curlInfo = curl_getinfo($ch);
    if(curl_error($ch)) {
        $unlockStatus = 'ERROR: '.curl_error($ch).print_r($curlInfo,1);
    }
    else {
        $unlockStatus = array(
            'status' => ($curlInfo['http_code'] == '204' ? 'ok' : 'Fail'), 
            'response' => htmlentities($response), 
            'curlInfo' => $curlInfo, 
        );
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    return $unlockStatus;
}
```

NB: In a more manual way you can get properties and unlock files from the command line with 2 cURL commands:

```
// GET RESOURCE PROPERTIES
curl -X PROPFIND '{path-to-resource}' -H 'Authorization:Basic {base64 encoded username:password}' -H 'Depth:1'

// UNLOCK A LOCKED FILE
curl -X UNLOCK '{path-to-resource}' -H 'Authorization: Basic {base64 encoded username:password}' -H 'Lock-Token: <{lock-token-from-first-request}>'
```

Comment: Thank you Christoff !! This is just what I was looking for. I already tried this by using curl, but did not get the params right... I´ll try your code!